# This code will constantly print three ones

Tags: php, html

I'm a beginner and I just can't seem to get this to work. Any suggestions? Please help.

Here's a portion of the code, saved under a php file

```php
 <?php
     /**check if enter is pressed*/
     if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {
        /**set vars to results*/
        $uname = isset($_POST['uname']);
        $upass = isset($_POST['upass']);
        $key = isset($_POST['key']);
        /**print results*/
        echo $uname;
        echo $upass;
        echo $key;
    }

  ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat gate</title>
    </head>
    <body align="center" valign="middle">
        <form action="index.php" method="POST">
            <tt>Enter your username</tt>
            <input type = "text" name ="uname" required>
            <tt>Enter your password:</tt>
            <input type = "password" name = "upass" required>
            <tt>Confirm key:</tt>
            <input type = "text" name = "key" required>
            <input type = "submit" name = "enter">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) returns a boolean. You want to retrieve the values themselves (after `isset`).

Comment: what @Jeto is saying is that you need something like `$uname = isset($_POST['uname']) ? $_POST['uname'] : '';`

Comment: Or perhaps just let go of the `isset`. Apart from the `if` you don't really need to super-supress any warnings for parameters that you're expecting. That construct is a little overadvertized on SO, but not overly suitable for beginners.

Comment: Can you explain further what you expect from that code and what **exactly** is not working as you've thought?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the isset in the variable assignment so change to this.

```
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$upass = $_POST['upass'];
$key   = $_POST['key'];
```

[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns 1 (true) if the variable you pass it is set, and 0 (false) if it is not set, meaning as all your varibles are set, 111 is been printed. If you want to check if they are set before you print them, you need an extra if statement.

Maybe something like this to check they are all set before printing them.

```
if (isset($_POST['uname'], $_POST['upass'], $_POST['key'])){
    echo $uname;
    echo $upass;
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: Just a note that `isset` accepts multiple arguments (no need to chain them with `&&`).